# Docker forking process

Tags: perl, docker

I have a problem with a Docker Container that should run the SmartHome Application "FHEM". The problem is that after the start the initial process forks into background and quits after that the docker Container stops.

How can i prevent this?

Comment: show a reproducer, at least the Dockerfile at the whole `docker run`

Comment: You can find the docker file here http://github.com/Phill93/docker-fhem

Comment: When you launch `sudo -u "$FHEMUSER" -H perl "$FHEMFILE" "$CONFIGFILE"` in a Linux system (and not in a container), does it work?

Comment: Yes but the process forks to background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tanktalus is right, making your software not fork would be the best approach.

If that is not possible, however, you have to make your container start script run as long as your serving process. There are two caveats to this:

1. The script has to terminate when the serving process terminates. Otherwise, docker would be unaware of its termination and the container would be kept running. Making sure your service is running with options such as `--restart=always` would have no effect.
2. On a comparable note it would be advantageous if the script also terminates with the same exit code as the serving process. This may make debugging issues easier.

Luckily, there is the bash command `wait` for that. Let's have an example:

```
$ cat docker_test.sh 
perl -e "sleep(5); exit(42);" &
wait `pgrep perl`
```

What happens here is that 1) `pgrep perl` will find the pid of the `perl` process sleeping in the background and 2) `wait` will wait for that process to terminate. Furthermore, `wait` will return the exit code of `perl`. Everything we need:

```
$ ./docker_test.sh 
$ echo $?
42
```

With docker we get this:

```
$ docker run -d -v `pwd`/docker_test.sh:/docker_test.sh ubuntu bash /docker_test.sh
537bdfc04554461da7dd6728ca721e4789a08e426adcc01a3359ed22fd16aa1f
[waiting 5 secs]
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                            PORTS               NAMES
537bdfc04554        ubuntu              "bash /docker_test.sh"   41 seconds ago       Exited (42) 34 seconds ago                            happy_almeida
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the software, you could emulate a number of other pieces of software that have a "don't fork into the background" mode, and add a flag to your startup that skips the background fork.  This would probably be the most straight-forward.

Alternatively, you can create an entrypoint script that starts your application and then simply adds a `while true; do sleep 1000; done` after starting the application.  That way, the entrypoint never returns, and the docker container continues to run.

Comment: issue is that if you do it like that, app does not know if docker is alive or not, ideally you run that loop each 120 seconds, check for child processes and break the loop if not.
this way you would at least get info it crashed.